# Mounted HDD into Ubuntu, now D: not accessable from Windows (Dual Boot)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, windows-10

Within Windows I have a C: Drive (SDD) (Disk 0) and D: Drive (HDD) (Disk 1)

Recently, I've begun dual-booting Ubuntu. In the setup, I have both windows and ubuntu on the SDD. To setup my linux similarly to how I use Windows, I wanted to utilize both drives. I have all my code and projects on D:. Unfortunately, I made the mistake of not creating a new partition within the HDD, and instead used almost the entirety of the Drive.

In Linux, I made directory /mnt/hdd then used `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/hdd` to achieve this, and it was successful, until I realized that I do not see any of the items within the Drive. I restarted and booted into Windows, where I was alarmed to find that I cannot access the D: drive at all, despite it being viewable from the Windows Partition Manager (This is the only place this drive is visible). Within that menu, all options to interact with this drive, Disk 1, are greyed out.

I have attempted to use `sudo umount` to attempt to undo the process, to no success. It appears to remount automatically, and the drive is not recovered in Windows on reboot.

In short, my issue is I want to recover access to an HDD in windows, that was lost after using `mount`

Comment: The commands that you have in your question will not prevent Windows from reading the hard drive. Were there other commands that you used as well, such as `fdisk` or `mkfs`? 

Comment: It sounds like you formatted or otherwise removed a partition or partitions on the HDD. Ouch.  Restore from backups.

Comment: You both pointed me in the correct direction. I think I must have ran a command without knowing/realizing. I've re-added a partition and corrected the mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Issue was that I somehow removed a partition. fdisk is a likely culprit. Beginner's mistake! **Fix was to reformat and then create a new partition for the HDD.** Answering to close